# Getting null value even node exits in firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting null value even if the node exits in Firebase Database. The line throwing the error is the following:

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.child(userNode).child(mobile.getText().toString()).exists()) {

            users usersData = dataSnapshot.child(userNode).child(mobile.getText().toString()).getValue(users.class);
            Log.d("hey","second log node exists "+usersData.getMobile());
            Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this,"User is: "+usersData.getUser(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

JSON File

```
    {
      "users" : {
        "54321" : {
          "Password" : "567",
          "Phone" : "54321",
          "Username" : "nik"
        }
      }
    }
```

The users class is perfect, the nodes have been created but I'm still getting null value.

Any idea on the reason?

Comment: It's impossible to say why this happens with the information you provided. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the changes that someone can quickly help. In this case, an MCVE should contain: 1) the code that attaches the listener, and gets called with `datasnapshot`, 2) the JSON at the point that you listen to (as text, **no** screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: edited sir please check

Comment: can you post your ref variable initialization ? and also, what is userNode and post your user class, we cant know what is happening without such information